# How to use the SDK to get latest modified objects under a prefix(last 2-3 objects)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I get say list of only 2 to 3 objects via SDK call to AWS to list S3 objects by latest date. I do not need to worry about pagination I think because all I am asking is the list of top/latest 2 to 3 objects

Answer (score 0):

I done something similar with a project I worked on. This linked helped me with that, you can have a look at the following AWS Documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html